# How to deploy a Richfaces 4 application in Eclipse Indigo using JBoss 7 and Maven 3

Tags: maven, richfaces, jboss7.x, eclipse-indigo

I'm trying to deploy an application in `Richfaces` using `Eclipse Indigo` as an IDE and `JBoss 7` as application server and `Maven 3`. But, `CSS` and `JS` are not working in this setup. Can any one here please help me on this.

Comment: what does your folder structure look like? this may be a resource issue. `mvn package jboss-as:deploy`should do the trick if everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar problem some time ago. How do you reference your js/css in your jsf? 
I think these links should be helpful:

- (for css) http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/
- (for js) http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-javascript-file-in-jsf/

Comment: Thanks for the help Peter.. The links you provided helped me on setting up required things.

Comment: I guess setting my answer as correct would be the proper way to say thanks :)